# MySQL sub query select statement inside Update query for deducting stocks

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

table_inventory:

```
item_no
item_name
item_qty
```

table_pos:

```
orderno
qty
```

I want to deduct the purchased item(qty) to the inventory items(item_qty). so i can update directly the table_inventory

```
UPDATE table_inventory 
SET item_qty = (item_qty - (SELECT qty FROM tblpos WHERE qty='" & txtqty.Text & "'))
WHERE item_no='" & txtitemno.Text & "'
```

I seem to have guess it right but whenever I tried the same item twice. I'll get the "subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: aren't these examples here missing a join on item_no. looks like it is  missing some logic

Comment: dont u have item_no in table_pos table?

Answer (score 0):

What about?:

```
UPDATE table_inventory 
SET 
    item_qty = (item_qty - (SELECT qty FROM tblpos WHERE qty='" & txtqty.Text & "' LIMIT 0,1)) 
WHERE item_no='" & txtitemno.Text & "'
```

You really should make an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so people can help you better.

Comment: sorry its my first time asking here.. i just wanna know if i have some errors in my sql statement? thanks

Comment: I already posted a suggestion by adding the limit in the subquery.
I can't unfortunately test it for you because I'm not going to invest time in recreeating your database.
If you would however create an sqlfiddle I'd might be more inclined to help in detail and so would others.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that query looks suspicious--selecting qty from the table where the qty value is as specified by the user.

Why not just use the user input, in txtqty.Text directly?

Secondly, as the error indicates, that SELECT is returning multiple rows with the same qty value. If that's what your query is going to be, you can simply add `DISTINCT` clause to get just one row with one column.

```
UPDATE table_inventory 
SET 
    item_qty = 
        (item_qty - (
                     SELECT DISTINCT qty 
                     FROM tblpos 
                     WHERE qty='" & txtqty.Text & "'
                     )
        )
WHERE item_no='" & txtitemno.Text & "'
```

Or simply, just use the user input itself.

Also, your query construction is prone to SQL injection as you are just reading the user input and appending it to your query without sanitizing them. You should take care of that too.

Comment: If you are deducing from another table, you should make sure that the WHERE clause filters match only one record, otherwise, it means there is some problem with the logic itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think u need `sum` of qty before you deduct, so my suggestion is as below,

```
UPDATE table_inventory 
SET item_qty = 
(item_qty - (SELECT sum(qty) FROM tblpos WHERE qty='" & txtqty.Text & "' group by qty))
WHERE item_no='" & txtitemno.Text & "'
```

Comment: I've tried it but whenever I input a number it deducts it from the stocks time three of the value I input